# Traçando mapa e obtendo quilometragem entre dois pontos

Tags: php, google-maps

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, e estou recebendo dois endereços por um campo de texto, e estou usando para calcular a distância a API Matrix do Google Maps, até ai beleza, mas eu queria também gerar um mapa mostrando esse caminho, e que esse caminho fosse exatamente o mesmo que a API Matrix utilizou para calcular a quilometragem. Resumindo, preciso traçar um trajeto entre dois pontos, e obter a quilometragem entre ele (para guardar em uma variavel). Me deem apenas um norte, é tudo que preciso. Obrigado.

Comment: O caminho direto ou mesmo um mapa como o do Google Maps?

Comment: Um mapa com o do google maps, traçando o caminho real entre dois pontos, como por exemplo: Salvador - São Paulo, mostrar o caminho (tipo gps) e a quilometragem entre as duas cidades.

Comment: Muito interessante a pergunta, acho que seria bacana deixar aberto para outras APIs além a do Google Maps (como [Here](http://here.com/), [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), etc.)

Comment: Se solucionar meu problema e o de quem precisar pode ser em qualquer API.

Comment: Eu não entendi se você já converteu o endereço para coordenadas, para obter a rota, se sim, posta teu js para ver o que precisa adicionar e/ou modificar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usando a [API V3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=pt-br) do google maps, você pode usar este exemplo, caso precise apenas de um norte.

**Javascript + Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Calcular distancia entre cidades (mapas e rotas)</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Parâmetro sensor é utilizado somente em dispositivos com GPS -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CalculaDistancia() {
            $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
            //Instanciar o DistanceMatrixService
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            //executar o DistanceMatrixService
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                  //Origem
                  origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()],
                  //Destino
                  destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()],
                  //Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                  //Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
                  //Vai chamar o callback
              }, callback);
        }
        //Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
        function callback(response, status) {
            //Verificar o Status
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
                //Se o status não for "OK"
                $('#litResultado').html(status);
            else {
                //Se o status for OK
                //Endereço de origem = response.originAddresses
                //Endereço de destino = response.destinationAddresses
                //Distância = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
                //Duração = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                $('#litResultado').html("<strong>Origem</strong>: " + response.originAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Destino:</strong> " + response.destinationAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Distância</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text +
                    " <br /><strong>Duração</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                    );
                //Atualizar o mapa
                $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses + "&output=embed");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" id="txtOrigem" class="field" style="width: 400px" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 400px" class="field" id="txtDestino" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Calcular dist&acirc;ncia" onclick="CalculaDistancia()" class="btnNew" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 0; clear: both">
        <iframe width="750" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0" id="map" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=são paulo&daddr=rio de janeiro&output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>
```

**Retorno do Json**

```
{ "destinationAddresses" : [ "Rio de Janeiro - RJ, República Federativa do Brasil" ],
       "originAddresses" : [ "São Paulo - SP, República Federativa do Brasil" ],
       "rows" : [ { "elements" : [ { "distance" : { "text" : "430 km",
              "value" : 430395
            },
          "duration" : { "text" : "4 horas 42 minutos",
              "value" : 16942
            },
          "status" : "OK"
        } ] } ]
}
```

Já utilizei este exemplo para uma aplicação e deu certo... 
Só alterar o que você precisa.

Fonte: http://cbsa.com.br/post/distancia-entre-cidades---google-maps-javascript-api-v3.aspx

Se tiver alguma dúvida, só falar, apesar de estar bem comentado, tem alguns detalhes de implementação, note que o uso de objetos javascript é bem forte na API.

Outro site com explicações detalhadas dos objetos:
http://tableless.com.br/api-google-maps-v3/

Comment: Consegui entender quase tudo, mas como nao tenho muito conhecimento de json me tira uma duvida, como faco pra passar o valor que ele me retorna pro php, pra poder manipular o dado?

Comment: Esse exemplo resolveu meu problema, eu só queria mesmo conseguir passar para o PHP a variável da distância em KM, e outra coisa, no mapa ele mostra também o tempo se for de avião. Tem como tirar?

Comment: Então, o que ocorre é o seguinte, a sua página php vai processar e vai renderizar o html, então o javascript vai ativar. Precisaria saber como está a sua aplicação para entender aonde o código poderia ser inserido, você pode fazer um post via ajax para salvar num banco de dados via php por exemplo. Qual a finalidade de enviar pro PHP, o que você precisa manipular exatamente?

Comment: Minha aplicação está quase igual esse exemplo, eu tenho 3 campos, destino e origem e carro, e estava querendo gerar o mapa com a rota e a quilometragem, bem, eu tenho uma tabela de carros no banco de dados, com consumo energético e poluição, ai eu queria pegar um dado desse ex: poluição, e multipliar pelo valor de KMs para obter um resultado e mostrar para o usuário. É isso.

Comment: Ok, você vai precisar de uma callback que acione uma requisição http via ajax, você vai passar o parãmetro distância e os outros parâmetros que você vai utilizar para o cálculo, mas aí, é conteúdo para mais uma pergunta, pois me parece um tanto complexo de responder sem ver o restante do código, eu não sei como está estruturado seu bd e estas outras informações para poder te sugerir algo mais concreto.

Comment: O carro seria um select, com o id do registro do carro, relacionando estas outras informações? Ou a pessoa vai digitar um modelo, e efetuar uma busca? Isto ficou um pouco vago para mim.

Comment: Ah, o carro ta num combobox, ela vai escolher o modelo e a partir dai, vai ser efetuado um select p retornar os dados do banco.