# Multiplicação simples em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tenho o código Google Maps v3, que calcula a distância entre dois pontos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Calcular distancia entre cidades (mapas e rotas)</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Parâmetro sensor é utilizado somente em dispositivos com GPS -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CalculaDistancia() {
            $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
            //Instanciar o DistanceMatrixService
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            //executar o DistanceMatrixService
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                  //Origem
                  origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()],
                  //Destino
                  destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()],
                  //Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                  //Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
                  //Vai chamar o callback
              }, callback);
        }
        //Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
        function callback(response, status) {
            //Verificar o Status
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
                //Se o status não for "OK"
                $('#litResultado').html(status);
            else {
                //Se o status for OK
                //Endereço de origem = response.originAddresses
                //Endereço de destino = response.destinationAddresses
                //Distância = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
                //Duração = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                $('#litResultado').html("<strong>Origem</strong>: " + response.originAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Destino:</strong> " + response.destinationAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Distância</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text +
                    " <br /><strong>Duração</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                    );
                //Atualizar o mapa
                $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses + "&output=embed");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" id="txtOrigem" class="field" style="width: 400px" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" style="width: 400px" class="field" id="txtDestino" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Calcular dist&acirc;ncia" onclick="CalculaDistancia()" class="btnNew" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 0 0; clear: both">
        <iframe width="750" scrolling="no" height="350" frameborder="0" id="map" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=são paulo&daddr=rio de janeiro&output=embed"></iframe>
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Como posso multiplicar a distância (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text) por x30, por exemplo?

Desde já agradeço!

(Crédito do código: [Marcelo Aymone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23859/tra%C3%A7ando-mapa-e-obtendo-quilometragem-entre-dois-pontos/23885#23885))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando precisa de multiplicar no meio de uma concatenação de string precisa usar parenteses.

No seu caso onde tem: `" + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text + "` pode usar assim:

```
" + (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text * 30) + "
```

Isto assumindo que esse `response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text` é tipo: *numero*.

Se fôr tipo: *string* vai ter de converter para numero primeiro com `parseInt` ou `parseFloat` primeiro. No código da resposta que indicou esse valor seria mesmo string, "430 Km". Nesse caso o `parseInt` lê somente os numeros e ignora "Km" limpando e convertendo.

Um exemplo seria:

```
    " + (parseInt(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text, 10) * 30) + "
```