# Multiplicação simples em JavaScript com decimal

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Como visto no tópico [Multiplicação simples em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44434/multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-simples-em-javascript), consegui multiplicar por x30 o valor **response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text** no script do Google Maps v3.

O Código final ficou assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Cálculo de distância</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Segoe, 'Segoe UI', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">

<div style="border: 2px solid #747474; padding: 10px; width: 800px;">
    <form method="post" action="default.aspx?id=205" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'btnSearch')" id="form1">
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>     <script type="text/javascript">
 
        function CalculaDistancia() {
            $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
            //Instanciar o DistanceMatrixService
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            //executar o DistanceMatrixService
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                  //Origem
                  origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()],
                  //Destino
                  destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()],
                  //Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                  //Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
                  //Vai chamar o callback
              }, callback);
        }
        //Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
        function callback(response, status) {
            //Verificar o Status
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
                //Se o status n�o for "OK"
                $('#litResultado').html(status);
            else {
                //Se o status for OK
                //Endere�o de origem = response.originAddresses
                //Endere�o de destino = response.destinationAddresses
                //Dist�ncia = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
                //Dura��o = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                $('#litResultado').html("<strong>Origem</strong>: " + response.originAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Destino:</strong> " + response.destinationAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Distância</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text +
                    " <br /><strong>Duração</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text +
     "<br /><strong>R$</strong> <input style='border: none; font-size: 26px;' type='text' value='" + (parseInt(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text, 10) * 30) + "'>"
                    );
                //Atualizar o mapa
                $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses + "&output=embed");
            }
        }
  
    </script>
    <table width="736" border="0" cellpadding="2" class="contact fleft" style="margin: 0 0 10px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="215" align="left"><label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem
            </strong><br>
              <span style="color:#E41E26;">(ex: rua pedro joao coeli limeira)</span></label></td>
            <td width="308"><input style="padding:2px; border: 2px solid #747474; color: #747474; text-transform:uppercase; height: 30px;" type="text" class="field" id="txtOrigem" size="50" /></td>
            <td width="2" rowspan="2"><svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 200.000000 200.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata></metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,200.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M905 1990 c-417 -45 -766 -345 -867 -746 -33 -130 -33 -361 0 -489
91 -349 367 -627 709 -714 443 -113 881 70 1115 464 182 307 171 731 -27 1035
-63 96 -199 232 -295 295 -178 116 -429 177 -635 155z m325 -95 c36 -9 115
-41 175 -70 192 -93 327 -228 420 -420 77 -158 90 -218 90 -405 0 -181 -13
-244 -81 -388 -96 -206 -240 -350 -445 -446 -145 -68 -208 -81 -389 -81 -131
0 -168 4 -235 23 -470 134 -753 580 -670 1057 65 369 343 654 726 740 85 19
319 14 409 -10z"/>
<path d="M1220 1866 c0 -4 9 -25 20 -47 101 -198 144 -475 93 -605 -27 -68
-65 -116 -121 -155 -38 -26 -42 -30 -19 -25 15 4 27 4 27 2 0 -3 -12 -12 -27
-21 -27 -15 -27 -16 -3 -10 14 4 43 19 65 34 161 109 227 461 124 663 -11 21
-21 38 -23 38 -1 0 3 -28 10 -62 8 -35 13 -83 13 -108 0 -45 0 -44 -22 30 -23
78 -83 204 -117 248 -11 13 -20 22 -20 18z"/>
<path d="M1524 1542 c-2 -142 -14 -222 -50 -331 -45 -135 -130 -232 -229 -261
-22 -7 -49 -16 -60 -20 -17 -7 -16 -9 10 -10 26 -1 27 -3 10 -10 -20 -8 -20
-9 1 -9 68 -3 177 68 250 163 102 130 145 242 143 376 l-1 75 -18 -82 c-11
-46 -23 -89 -27 -97 -4 -8 -8 54 -8 137 -1 84 -5 162 -10 174 -7 15 -10 -15
-11 -105z"/>
<path d="M947 1372 c-20 -45 -57 -80 -94 -87 -12 -3 -34 -7 -47 -10 -14 -3
-28 -16 -36 -34 -6 -16 -20 -37 -31 -47 -11 -10 -19 -30 -19 -47 0 -28 1 -29
13 -13 14 19 37 19 108 1 18 -5 31 -1 42 10 27 26 20 36 -12 18 -27 -16 -30
-16 -55 0 -29 20 -35 57 -11 77 9 8 30 11 55 7 31 -4 40 -2 40 10 0 8 11 24
24 34 26 20 50 77 44 105 -2 11 -10 1 -21 -24z"/>
<path d="M235 1380 c20 -72 82 -174 153 -252 55 -61 27 -44 -51 30 -70 67 -75
68 -28 2 l25 -35 -33 30 c-63 56 -16 -8 52 -71 186 -175 522 -230 657 -108 46
42 70 89 70 141 0 51 -29 83 -73 83 l-32 -1 27 -15 c80 -43 8 -180 -113 -214
-181 -52 -443 101 -609 356 -28 43 -48 68 -45 54z"/>
<path d="M1655 1358 c-2 -7 -12 -35 -21 -63 -46 -142 -138 -295 -213 -354 -57
-46 -126 -73 -187 -74 -44 -2 -51 -4 -38 -14 14 -10 13 -12 -3 -16 -37 -10 64
-6 107 4 149 34 348 230 374 369 7 32 5 31 -24 -20 -17 -30 -40 -64 -51 -75
-16 -17 -15 -9 9 45 25 56 38 99 57 193 4 20 -3 23 -10 5z"/>
<path d="M292 1086 c19 -36 110 -145 136 -162 13 -8 21 -18 18 -21 -3 -3 -27
10 -53 29 -74 53 -79 54 -49 16 67 -88 201 -149 331 -151 84 -1 143 19 176 59
12 15 12 17 0 9 -11 -6 -13 -4 -8 8 4 11 -3 9 -30 -8 -114 -78 -257 -31 -430
141 -56 55 -97 92 -91 80z"/>
<path d="M1036 831 c-94 -128 -117 -280 -70 -466 16 -63 54 -158 60 -152 2 2
-5 30 -16 62 -30 86 -24 101 8 20 27 -68 90 -177 110 -189 6 -3 -9 28 -33 69
-76 133 -123 316 -110 425 8 66 35 138 70 191 34 52 23 50 -15 -3 -42 -57 -38
-31 5 32 46 68 39 76 -9 11z"/>
<path d="M410 841 c19 -18 62 -45 94 -61 64 -32 56 -39 -15 -15 l-44 15 24
-20 c69 -59 255 -66 350 -15 51 28 95 75 66 71 -8 -1 -22 -9 -32 -18 -81 -71
-241 -63 -383 19 -25 15 -56 33 -70 41 -17 10 -14 4 10 -17z"/>
<path d="M935 759 c-37 -73 -65 -191 -65 -273 0 -74 31 -233 50 -264 11 -16
11 -16 6 1 -3 9 -8 48 -11 85 l-5 67 15 -49 c23 -69 27 -52 9 35 -22 107 -15
313 13 392 12 31 20 57 17 57 -2 0 -15 -23 -29 -51z"/>
<path d="M1050 746 c-23 -61 -31 -149 -20 -219 10 -72 59 -186 100 -237 17
-22 17 -17 -5 33 -30 68 -33 95 -6 51 30 -50 48 -53 19 -3 -61 105 -96 259
-80 348 10 55 7 66 -8 27z"/>
</g>
</svg></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino
            </strong><br>
              <span style="color:#E41E26;">(ex: av brasil rio de janeiro)</span></label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="field" id="txtDestino" style="padding:2px; border: 2px solid #747474; color: #747474; text-transform:uppercase; height: 30px;" value="R. Gen. Rondon, 538 - Vila Labaki, SP, 13486-442, Brasil" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><hr><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="padding:5px; border: 2px solid red; font-weight:bold; color: #FFF; background-color: #E41E26; cursor: pointer;" type="button" class="btnNew" onClick="CalculaDistancia()" value="Calcular" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    


<div style="padding: 10px 0 0; clear: both"><iframe width="795" scrolling="no" height="500" frameborder="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=rua pedro joao coeli 223 limeira&amp;daddr=rua gen rondon 538 limeira&amp;output=embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" id="map" style="border: 2px solid #747474;"></iframe><center><small>2015 &copy; Fênix Guinchos</small></center></div>
           
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

theForm.oldSubmit = theForm.submit;
theForm.submit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit;

theForm.oldOnSubmit = theForm.onsubmit;
theForm.onsubmit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionOnSubmit;
WebForm_AutoFocus('btnSearch');//]]>
</script>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Contudo, a multiplicação não considera as casas decimais, multiplicando somente os números inteiros. Como fazer uma multiplicação considerando os decimais?
Obrigado!

Comment: Usas ponto ou virgula para os decimais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiro fazeres uma função para isso para não ficar confuso.

Se me lembro da pergunta anterior essa string tem `"430 Km"`, mas no caso de teres `"430,2 Km"` então tens de mudar essa virgula para ponto antes de poderes usar o `parseFloat`. Podes fazer isso com `.replace(',','.');`, que funciona mesmo que tenhas um ponto inicialmente.

Fazendo uma função com isso poderia ser assim:

```
function multiplicar(string, multiplicador){
    var numero = string.replace(',','.');
    return parseFloat(numero) * multiplicador;
}
```

e no código podes usar:

```
"<br /><strong>R$</strong> <input style='border: none; font-size: 26px;' type='text' value='" + multiplicar(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text, 30) + "'>"
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Sergio! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

[Renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20098/renan), neste caso você não precisa fazer conversão, pois a API do Google retorna o valor em texto e o valor numérico. Se você debugar o retorno da variável **response.rows[0].elements[0].distance**, terá o seguinte retorno, `Object { text: "152 km", value: 151648 }`. No entanto o retorno numérico está em metros, caso você queira trabalhar com o valor em KM só terá que fazer a conversão, e seguindo seu exemplo ficará algo assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Cálculo de distância</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Segoe, 'Segoe UI', 'DejaVu Sans', 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">

<div style="border: 2px solid #747474; padding: 10px; width: 800px;">
    <form method="post" action="default.aspx?id=205" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'btnSearch')" id="form1">
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>     <script type="text/javascript">
 
        function CalculaDistancia() {
            $('#litResultado').html('Aguarde...');
            //Instanciar o DistanceMatrixService
            var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
            //executar o DistanceMatrixService
            service.getDistanceMatrix(
              {
                  //Origem
                  origins: [$("#txtOrigem").val()],
                  //Destino
                  destinations: [$("#txtDestino").val()],
                  //Modo (DRIVING | WALKING | BICYCLING)
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                  //Sistema de medida (METRIC | IMPERIAL)
                  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
                  //Vai chamar o callback
              }, callback);
        }
        //Tratar o retorno do DistanceMatrixService
        function callback(response, status) {
            //Verificar o Status
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
                //Se o status n�o for "OK"
                $('#litResultado').html(status);
            else {
                //Se o status for OK
                //Endere�o de origem = response.originAddresses
                //Endere�o de destino = response.destinationAddresses
                //Dist�ncia = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
                //Dura��o = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text
                $('#litResultado').html("<strong>Origem</strong>: " + response.originAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Destino:</strong> " + response.destinationAddresses +
                    "<br /><strong>Distância</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text +
                    " <br /><strong>Duração</strong>: " + response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text +
     "<br /><strong>R$</strong> <input style='border: none; font-size: 26px;' type='text' value='" + ((response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value)/1000 * 30) + "'>"
                    );
                //Atualizar o mapa
                $("#map").attr("src", "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + response.originAddresses + "&daddr=" + response.destinationAddresses + "&output=embed");
            }
        }
  
    </script>
    <table width="736" border="0" cellpadding="2" class="contact fleft" style="margin: 0 0 10px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="215" align="left"><label for="txtOrigem"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de origem
            </strong><br>
              <span style="color:#E41E26;">(ex: rua pedro joao coeli limeira)</span></label></td>
            <td width="308"><input style="padding:2px; border: 2px solid #747474; color: #747474; text-transform:uppercase; height: 30px;" type="text" class="field" id="txtOrigem" size="50" /></td>
            <td width="2" rowspan="2"><svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 200.000000 200.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata></metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,200.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M905 1990 c-417 -45 -766 -345 -867 -746 -33 -130 -33 -361 0 -489
91 -349 367 -627 709 -714 443 -113 881 70 1115 464 182 307 171 731 -27 1035
-63 96 -199 232 -295 295 -178 116 -429 177 -635 155z m325 -95 c36 -9 115
-41 175 -70 192 -93 327 -228 420 -420 77 -158 90 -218 90 -405 0 -181 -13
-244 -81 -388 -96 -206 -240 -350 -445 -446 -145 -68 -208 -81 -389 -81 -131
0 -168 4 -235 23 -470 134 -753 580 -670 1057 65 369 343 654 726 740 85 19
319 14 409 -10z"/>
<path d="M1220 1866 c0 -4 9 -25 20 -47 101 -198 144 -475 93 -605 -27 -68
-65 -116 -121 -155 -38 -26 -42 -30 -19 -25 15 4 27 4 27 2 0 -3 -12 -12 -27
-21 -27 -15 -27 -16 -3 -10 14 4 43 19 65 34 161 109 227 461 124 663 -11 21
-21 38 -23 38 -1 0 3 -28 10 -62 8 -35 13 -83 13 -108 0 -45 0 -44 -22 30 -23
78 -83 204 -117 248 -11 13 -20 22 -20 18z"/>
<path d="M1524 1542 c-2 -142 -14 -222 -50 -331 -45 -135 -130 -232 -229 -261
-22 -7 -49 -16 -60 -20 -17 -7 -16 -9 10 -10 26 -1 27 -3 10 -10 -20 -8 -20
-9 1 -9 68 -3 177 68 250 163 102 130 145 242 143 376 l-1 75 -18 -82 c-11
-46 -23 -89 -27 -97 -4 -8 -8 54 -8 137 -1 84 -5 162 -10 174 -7 15 -10 -15
-11 -105z"/>
<path d="M947 1372 c-20 -45 -57 -80 -94 -87 -12 -3 -34 -7 -47 -10 -14 -3
-28 -16 -36 -34 -6 -16 -20 -37 -31 -47 -11 -10 -19 -30 -19 -47 0 -28 1 -29
13 -13 14 19 37 19 108 1 18 -5 31 -1 42 10 27 26 20 36 -12 18 -27 -16 -30
-16 -55 0 -29 20 -35 57 -11 77 9 8 30 11 55 7 31 -4 40 -2 40 10 0 8 11 24
24 34 26 20 50 77 44 105 -2 11 -10 1 -21 -24z"/>
<path d="M235 1380 c20 -72 82 -174 153 -252 55 -61 27 -44 -51 30 -70 67 -75
68 -28 2 l25 -35 -33 30 c-63 56 -16 -8 52 -71 186 -175 522 -230 657 -108 46
42 70 89 70 141 0 51 -29 83 -73 83 l-32 -1 27 -15 c80 -43 8 -180 -113 -214
-181 -52 -443 101 -609 356 -28 43 -48 68 -45 54z"/>
<path d="M1655 1358 c-2 -7 -12 -35 -21 -63 -46 -142 -138 -295 -213 -354 -57
-46 -126 -73 -187 -74 -44 -2 -51 -4 -38 -14 14 -10 13 -12 -3 -16 -37 -10 64
-6 107 4 149 34 348 230 374 369 7 32 5 31 -24 -20 -17 -30 -40 -64 -51 -75
-16 -17 -15 -9 9 45 25 56 38 99 57 193 4 20 -3 23 -10 5z"/>
<path d="M292 1086 c19 -36 110 -145 136 -162 13 -8 21 -18 18 -21 -3 -3 -27
10 -53 29 -74 53 -79 54 -49 16 67 -88 201 -149 331 -151 84 -1 143 19 176 59
12 15 12 17 0 9 -11 -6 -13 -4 -8 8 4 11 -3 9 -30 -8 -114 -78 -257 -31 -430
141 -56 55 -97 92 -91 80z"/>
<path d="M1036 831 c-94 -128 -117 -280 -70 -466 16 -63 54 -158 60 -152 2 2
-5 30 -16 62 -30 86 -24 101 8 20 27 -68 90 -177 110 -189 6 -3 -9 28 -33 69
-76 133 -123 316 -110 425 8 66 35 138 70 191 34 52 23 50 -15 -3 -42 -57 -38
-31 5 32 46 68 39 76 -9 11z"/>
<path d="M410 841 c19 -18 62 -45 94 -61 64 -32 56 -39 -15 -15 l-44 15 24
-20 c69 -59 255 -66 350 -15 51 28 95 75 66 71 -8 -1 -22 -9 -32 -18 -81 -71
-241 -63 -383 19 -25 15 -56 33 -70 41 -17 10 -14 4 10 -17z"/>
<path d="M935 759 c-37 -73 -65 -191 -65 -273 0 -74 31 -233 50 -264 11 -16
11 -16 6 1 -3 9 -8 48 -11 85 l-5 67 15 -49 c23 -69 27 -52 9 35 -22 107 -15
313 13 392 12 31 20 57 17 57 -2 0 -15 -23 -29 -51z"/>
<path d="M1050 746 c-23 -61 -31 -149 -20 -219 10 -72 59 -186 100 -237 17
-22 17 -17 -5 33 -30 68 -33 95 -6 51 30 -50 48 -53 19 -3 -61 105 -96 259
-80 348 10 55 7 66 -8 27z"/>
</g>
</svg></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><label for="txtDestino"><strong>Endere&ccedil;o de destino
            </strong><br>
              <span style="color:#E41E26;">(ex: av brasil rio de janeiro)</span></label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="field" id="txtDestino" style="padding:2px; border: 2px solid #747474; color: #747474; text-transform:uppercase; height: 30px;" value="R. Gen. Rondon, 538 - Vila Labaki, SP, 13486-442, Brasil" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><hr><span id="litResultado">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="padding:5px; border: 2px solid red; font-weight:bold; color: #FFF; background-color: #E41E26; cursor: pointer;" type="button" class="btnNew" onClick="CalculaDistancia()" value="Calcular" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    


<div style="padding: 10px 0 0; clear: both"><iframe width="795" scrolling="no" height="500" frameborder="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=rua pedro joao coeli 223 limeira&amp;daddr=rua gen rondon 538 limeira&amp;output=embed" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" id="map" style="border: 2px solid #747474;"></iframe><center><small>2015 &copy; Fênix Guinchos</small></center></div>
           
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

theForm.oldSubmit = theForm.submit;
theForm.submit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit;

theForm.oldOnSubmit = theForm.onsubmit;
theForm.onsubmit = WebForm_SaveScrollPositionOnSubmit;
WebForm_AutoFocus('btnSearch');//]]>
</script>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `+1` por referir (eu não sabia) que esse retorno do Google Maps já tem um `value: ` em metros, numérico.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `parseFloat` ao invés de converter a variável pra inteiro.

```js
var exemplo = "30.4";
alert("Int: " + parseInt(exemplo) * 30);
alert("Float: " + parseFloat(exemplo) * 30);
```

Nessa parte:

```
<strong>R$</strong> <input style='border: none; font-size: 26px;' type='text' value='" + (parseFloat(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text) * 30) + "'>"
```